# Window.location.redirect only works while debugging

Tags: javascript

I created a function to check different values in input fields. If all requirements are fulfilled I want to route the user to another page. I struggled a lot and now it only works in firefox while I´m debugging, otherwise it stays on the initial pag.

```
function login() {
    var username = document.getElementById("username").value;
    var password = document.getElementById("password").value;
    var password2 = document.getElementById("password2").value;
    var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
    var checkBox = document.getElementById("conditions").value;
    if (password != password2) {
        alert("Passwords don't match");
    } else if (password.length < 6) {
        alert("The password has to be atleast 6 characters");
    } else if (checkBox != "on") {
        alert("You have to agree to the terms");
    } else if (username.length < 1) {
        alert("Enter a username");
    } else if (password == password2 && checkBox == "on") {
        window.location.replace("url");
    } else {
        alert("Something went wrong");
    }
}
```

Comment: i dont see any major issue here, few things to mention: `.value` on checkbox element return value even when checkbox is not checked, you should use `.checked` instead. and this: `} else if (password == password2 && checkBox == "on") {` is automatically allways true because it's "chained" with same condition before, so there is most likely problem somewhere else.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to load another webpage in current window by modifying the `window.location` object, then you can do it by few ways:

1. window.location.replace

```
window.location.replace('https://your-url.com');
```

2. window.location.assign

```
window.location.assign('https://your-url.com');
```

The Location.assign() method causes the window to load and display the document at the URL specified. After the navigation occurs, the user can navigate back to the page that called Location.assign() by pressing the "back" button.

3. window.location.href

```
window.location.href = 'https://your-url.com';
```

In first two methods, there might some problems in few cases and these might not work
example:
If the assignment can't happen because of a security violation, a DOMException of the SECURITY_ERROR type is thrown. This happens if the origin of the script calling the method is different from the origin of the page originally described by the Location object, mostly when the script is hosted on a different domain.

If the provided URL is not valid, a DOMException of the SYNTAX_ERROR type is thrown.

you can use any one of these.